# Is there a noun meaning: person who accepts bribes?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word meaning *a person who takes bribes*? *Crook* is too
informal and encompasses too many other things.

I'm looking for *a single noun* that might describe such a person!

Example of usage:

> Do you think he might have been bribed?
>
> No, if he were a _______ I would have known.

Comment: "Bribee" is not used to often, but it IS a word. I don't think there's another formal term, except maybe "corrupt".

Comment: @henchmanjustin "corruptible" springs to mind.

Comment: I thought about "corruptible" too, but I figured if they actually accept bribes they're not corruptible, they're already corrupt.

Comment: @henchmanjustin Is it an adjective or a noun that you're looking for?

Comment: Politician? :-)

Comment: @henchmanjustin Misneac makes a good point, I think people are answering different questions here.  So, do you mean a word for someone who is open to being bribed (_venal/corruptible_) or someone who is actually in receipt of a bribe (_bribee_)?

Comment: You could probably resolve the confusion by providing an [example sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info), which is required in any case. ("About single-word-requests:
This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE DEMONSTRATING HOW THE WORD WOULD BE USED")

Comment: If someone was open to bribes then it would likely be said that they can be `bought` or `paid off`. E.g `Most public officials cannot be bought.`

Comment: Another non-noun option is ["on the take"](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/be-on-the-take):  "If he were on the take, I would have known."

Answer (score 15):

The appropriate word is **venal**, meaning bribable from the Latin *venalis*, sale.  The venal politician is one whose influence is literally for sale.

Comment: Good show. I forgot "venal".

Comment: this is not a noun

Answer (score 3):

***[Purchasable](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/purchasable):***

> - Capable of being bribed; venal: *a purchasable senator.*

or

***[Corruptible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corruptible):***

> - Capable of being corrupted: *corruptible judges.*

The Free Dictionsty

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with just "corrupt"?

Answer (score 0):

Consider something as simple as **bribable**:

> bribable: open to improper influence and **especially bribery**
>   Example: *corruption in that country is so widespread that there are few public officials who are not **bribable***

([M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/bribable))

> bribable: capable of being bribed

(Webster's Unabridged)

If you need a popular word that any Anglophone understands, I suggest **[corrupt](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=corrupt)**:

> **Venal** or dishonest
>   *a corrupt mayor.*

(American Heritage Dictionary)

I like "venal" very much (was about to post it myself), but I'm not sure how many native speakers are familiar with it. So it depends on the target audience. For what it's worth, here's an Ngram demonstrating the popularity of "venal" vs "corrupt" vs other options:

[image]

Comment: ***Bribable*** - capable of being corrupted; "corruptible judges"; "dishonest politicians"; "a purchasable senator"; "a venal police officer" http://www.thefreedictionary.com/bribable

Comment: I was writing the same answer. :)

Comment: @Josh61 I have an offline Webster's Unabridged, from which the definition came. But I also updated my answer to include another (online) source for my definition.

Comment: @Rathony And I was about to post "venal", but deadrat beat me to it by 10 seconds or so :)

Answer (score 0):

"grafter" might work. See
https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/is-it-grifter-or-grafter-usage-difference-grift-graft

Answer (score -1):

Venal is those who accepts money in exchange of secret service .It is broadly used to describe corruption .But ,I will point out here ,Bribe is broader it may be used many dimensions. Money is also form of bribe so are other services.
So ,Venal can be used ,given the context should also be considered.

Comment: This answer suggests a word that has already been in an answer since 2015. It is also chock full of grammatical and formatting errors.

Answer (score -2):

[***subvertible***](http://www.yourdictionary.com/subvertible#wiktionary)

> subvert
>
> (*by extension*)
>
> : undermine or corrupt, as in morals
>
> Origin of subvert
>   Middle English subverten ; from Middle French subvertir ; from Classical Latin subvertere ; from sub-, sub- + vertere, to turn: see verse
>   [Your Dictionary]l(http://www.yourdictionary.com/subvert#yHLbGASEEHAHtsIw.99)
>
> :  to pervert or corrupt by an undermining of morals, allegiance, or faith [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subvert)

***tamperable***

> tamper
>
> : to use corrupt practices such as bribery or blackmail
>
> : (usually followed by with) to attempt to influence or corrupt, esp by bribery: *to tamper with the jury* [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tampered)